# How to use AJAX in wordpress front end?

Tags: ajax

I have two inputs in an HTML Widget block on a post. What I need to do: send the inputs (from the html widget) value to AJAX, construct and execute a query, render a table with the results back on the page where the inputs are. I've been researching and so far haven't found exactly my situation. I tried using the code below but I keep getting the ajax obj url is undefined. I even tried using the full file path to the admin-ajax.php file but I must not have the correct path. My question then is, is it possible to interact with the backend in this manner or will I need to create my own plugin?

```
$.ajax({
       type: 'POST',
       url: my_ajax_obj.ajax_url,//tried https://hostsite.com/public_html/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php
       dataType: "JSON",
       data: {action : 'retrieve_data', search_by : searchby , ui : input},
       success: function (response){
           console.log(resonse);
       },
       error: function(xhr,status,error){
           var err = eval("(" + xhr.responseText + ")");
           console.log(err.Message);
       }
    });
```

Comment: I can't tell from your question what action hook you're trying to use; WordPress provides [`wp_ajax_nopriv_{$action}`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_ajax_nopriv_action/) for AJAX use when a user's not logged in (ie, has no privileges).